# how to get file size in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using info() but it shows the file_size => 0

```
 $dir = new Folder('./path_to_folder/');
 $files = $dir->find('.*\.pdf');

 foreach($files as $file){
      debug($file); // here is name of file name
      $file = new File($file);
      debug($file->info());
 }
```

I can also get the size with php.

```
debug(filesize($dir->path.'\/'.$file));
```

How to show the file size by cakephp File component?

Comment: How do you use `info()`? Please add that to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a `File` object for each file name returned by `$dir->find()`.

Also note that `File::info()` only contains file size information from CakePHP 2.1 onwards.

There's an example in the docs:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $file = new File($dir->pwd() . DS . $file);

    // Now call size() on that file object
    $size = $file->size();

    // Alternatively, use info() if your version of CakePHP is at least 2.1
    $info = $file->info();
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I was writing the path statically

Answer (score 0):

You can call method size() on file object:

http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-File.html#_size